# Azure SQL - Managed Identity with a Security Group

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I've got an app service with a system generated managed identity setup, I've also got an azure SQL database setup with AAD admin setup, with the admin pointing to a security group (which I'm a member of). I'm trying to use an EXTERNAL_GROUP which contains the appservice managed identity to give rights to access the Azure SQL database.

My Azure app service connects to my database using the following connection string :

```
Server=tcp:<databaseserver>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication='Active Directory Default';
```

The security group which is setup is called `database-readerwriter-test` which has my app service as a member, i've logged in to the database as an admin and run the following

```sql
    CREATE USER [database-readerwriter-test] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
    GO
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [database-readerwriter-test]
    GO
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [database-readerwriter-test]
    GO
```

When I trigger a database call from the appservice I get the following error.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
```

If I add my appservice directly to the database (rather than the group that the appservice is a member of) I am able to connect to the database (using the following script)

```
    CREATE USER [test-webapp] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
    GO
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [test-webapp]
    GO
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [test-webapp]
    GO
```

Here is the state of my database_principals. I've checked that the ObjectID align to the Groups in AAD.

Is it possible to use EXTERNAL_GROUP which hold the appservices / azure functions to connect to the database using the managed identity so I can manage the addition of these in AAD rather than having to add via SQL.

[image]

Comment: do you have permission to list/view groups in AAD ?

Comment: have you read this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identity-best-practice-recommendations#limitation-of-using-managed-identities-for-authorization? you may have to wait few hours before the tokne get refreshed. i did try and encounter the same. if you turn off and on managed identity and re assigned that work => not ideal but this is not something you will change all lot tho

Comment: @Thomas thanks. It was the expiry of the tokens that was the missing part

Comment: Good to hear you managed to get it working :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use EXTERNAL_GROUP which hold the appservices / azure functions to connect to the database using the managed identity so I can manage the addition of these in AAD rather than having to add via SQL.

Yes, it is possible to use EXTERNAL_GROUP which hold the managed identity of your function or app service.

I built out a quick function app using the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-azure-sql-vs-code?source=recommendations&tabs=in-process%2Cv1&pivots=programming-language-csharp). I inputted the same connection string you are using in the app's code. I'm able to run the http function trigger and create new rows into the table. I can confirm in the sign of logs of the corresponding Enterprise application, of the function app, that it succeeds in connecting to the SQL database. I would suggest checking the managed identity sign in logs and see if you notice any "Failure" events.

TestGroup Members including functionapp:

[image: TestGroup Members including functionapp]

TestGroup show in database principals:

[image: TestGroup show in database principals]

Managed Identity Sign in Log:

[image: Managed Identity Sign in Log]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use an Azure AD-based security group (`EXTERNAL_GROUP`) to manage access to Azure SQL Database for Managed Identities associated with Azure App Services or Azure Functions. To do this, ensure that the Managed Identity is a member of the group, create a database user for the group within the SQL Database, assign the necessary roles (e.g., `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`) to that user, and ensure the Azure AD admin of the database server has the required permissions. Keep up with Azure updates, and refer to the Azure documentation for the latest guidance: [Azure SQL Database authentication and authorization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview).